# How to structure data in an NDB/Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: database-design, google-cloud-datastore

I need some help thinking about how to structure some data in an NDB. I have a reasonable amount (although I would suspect some would call small) of finance data that I would like to be able to store to show to my users.

Each project has (potentially) multiple cost centres and each cost centre will have multiple tasks that have a spend for each of our trading periods (12 a year).

I believe that this structure is logical but I want to check before building it:

`Project -> Cost Centre -> Task -> Transaction`

Where the `Task` is a the parent of the `Transaction` and the `Cost Centre` is the parent of the `Task` etc.

Is this logical? Considering that there would a couple of thousand new transactions added every month I don't want to set myself up with an inefficient structure.

**Update:** 
I am thinking about efficiency in terms of creating something that makes it easy to work with as opposed to efficiency in terms of processing power. I am sure that Google has the horse power but I want to help myself by making the data easy to work with.

In the above example I would want to display the user a table of project spend, grouped by `cost centre` then `task` with `trading periods` as column headers - much like a pivot table. I would like to know if would be easier to have multiple levels and worry about accessing information up and down the hierarchy or have one level with more properties but a large number of transactions assigned to the project?

Comment: This depends greatly on the use to which the datastore will be put. Are you sure you need to optimise this datastore? 2,000 is a very small number of transactions

Comment: I guess I am thinking about efficiency in terms of creating something that makes it easy to work with as opposed to efficiency in terms of processing power. I am sure that Google has the horse power but I want to help myself by making the data easy to work with.

In the above example I would want to display the user a table of project spend, grouped by cost centre then task then transaction, with trading periods as column headers - much like a pivot table. 

I would like to know if its better to have multiple levels or have one level with more properties?

Answer (score 0):

I think [HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) provides an important paradigm for NoSQL design.

"Hypermedia as the Engine of Application State" is a core principal in RESTful architecture.

Basically, I'm suggesting you think in terms of writing entity properties that are not merely passive data, but that actually supply API users with a set of code fragments or URI fragments that together answer the question, "Ok, what can I do with this bit of data?"

Given a particular *Kind*, you'd have one special entity of that kind, stored by name, not by id, whose properties serve to document the things that can be done with that kind.

So, for example, if you have "task" as a *Kind*, you'd have one special entity of kind "task", stored by "name=usageTask, with a property *lookUpCostCenter* containing a JSON template of a [lookup](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/datasets/lookup) request body for getting the "cost center" of any of the "task" entities.

That's probably a trivial example, but hopefully it clarifies.

My point is that, HATEOAS can serve as a powerful replacement for the relational integrity mechanisms of traditional RDBMs.